# Is there a reliable way to have finalization code run for a Hive UDF?

Tags: hive

I have some setup code that goes into the Hive UDF constructors. The code runs on each TaskTracker that is invoked for running the map/reduce jobs. This is working fine.There is however no tearDown()/close() type of method defined in the UDF abstract class.  Any suggestions on how to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive version 11 GenericUDF now has what I was seeking:

```
  /**
   * Close GenericUDF.
   * This is only called in runtime of MapRedTask.
   */
  public void close() throws IOException {
  }
```